# VueJs Transition Not working as Dynamic component

Tags: vue.js, transition, custom-component, vuejs3

### Goal:

Use dynamic components to create custom reusable transition components for **Vue V3**.
`vue2-transitions` [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-transitions) package uses the same method as below and it does not work with v3, So I decided to make a simple one for myself.

#### CustomTransition.Vue

```html
<component
  :is="group ? 'transition-group' : 'transition'"
  enter-active-class="fadeInDown"
  leave-active-class="fadeOutUp"
>
  <slot></slot>
</component>
```

### SomeOtherComponent.vue

```html
<div>
  <custom-transition>
    <span v-if="show">This does not work.</span>
  </custom-transition>
</div>
```

This does not work, I have no clue why. The `<transition>` element is rendered like this.

```html
<transition
  enter-active-class="fadeInDown"
  leave-active-class="fadeOutUp"
>
      <span>This does not work.</span>
</transition>
```

### But,

When I rewrite the `CustomComponent.vue` like this.

```html
<transition
  enter-active-class="fadeInDown"
  leave-active-class="fadeOutUp"
>
  <slot></slot>
</transition>
```

It is working perfectly fine.

## Edit

I've Added a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarangnx/t9L4fznc/23/), in case someone wants to try something out.

Comment: please share the css

Comment: I am using [animate.css](https://animate.style/) for animations. I did not post the full name in above question, which doesn't really matter. Full name would be `animate__animated animate__fadeInDown` and `animate__animated animate__fadeOutUp`.

Comment: The issue seems to be with dynamic component `<component :is="componentType">`.
It is working when i use names of global components that i've defined, but does not work with vue.js `transition` component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the solution from vue community.
[link to working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarangnx/t9L4fznc/25/)

For this component to work:

```html
<component
  :is="group ? 'transition-group' : 'transition'"
  enter-active-class="fadeInDown"
  leave-active-class="fadeOutUp"
>
  <slot></slot>
</component>
```

Import the `Transition` and `TransitionGroup` components explicitly in the component and register them.

```js
import { Transition, TransitionGroup } from 'vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Transition,
    TransitionGroup,
  },
  data() {
    return { show: false };
  }
}
```

link to [github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/2238) in `vue-next` repo.